# Spring Jdbctemplate with PostgreSQL: connection already closed when accesing java.sql.Array

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, jdbctemplate

I am using the **Spring's JdbcTemplate** with PostgreSQL. When my application comes to executing the below lines of code, an error is thrown. The method contains other read-only query-executions chained in a row, before it comes to that particular line.

The jdbcTemplate seems to close the connection, before the **java.sql.Array** can be extacted from the Map.

```
public void writeGeoRelation(Long id){

    ...

    List<Map<String, Object>> list = jdbcTemplate.queryForList(sql);
    for (Map<String, Object> map : list) {
        Long[] arr = (Long[]) ((Array) map.get("foo")).getArray(); //Erroneous line
    }
}
```

This is the stack trace:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: This connection has been closed.
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Connection.checkClosed(AbstractJdbc2Connection.java:822)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc3.AbstractJdbc3Connection.prepareStatement(AbstractJdbc3Connection.java:273)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Connection.prepareStatement(AbstractJdbc2Connection.java:301)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.TypeInfoCache.getArrayDelimiter(TypeInfoCache.java:337)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Array.buildArrayList(AbstractJdbc2Array.java:372)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Array.getArrayImpl(AbstractJdbc2Array.java:160)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Array.getArray(AbstractJdbc2Array.java:128)
    at com.company.geo.director.GeoDirector.writeGeoRelation(GeoDirector.java:438)
```

Do you know how I can **force the connection to stay open** without regressing to plain Jdbc? I'd really like to stay with Spring Jdbc.

Comment: Can you also highlight if this is a part of a transaction ? I suspect it is also depends on the max time out.

Comment: @dharam The above code snippet is part of a method that executes several queries, one after onother ... or what exectly do you mean by transaction?

Comment: Ok..The concept of transaction is such that if there are multiple queries to database (consisting of few updates etc) then every thing which is in a transaction will either be successful or everything rollbacks. It also results in closing the connections. THat might cause an issue as well.

Comment: ... but there are no updates/inserts in that method up to that point. Nevertheless i will try to wrap it into a transaction and look what happens. (+1 for the brief oneliner on transactions)

Comment: @dharam You were right. Wrapping the method with a Transactional annotation solved the problem. If you write an answer I will accept it!

Comment: OK then .. I will add an answer to the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might consider using `@Transactional` over your methods in `DAO` or Service from where the `DAO` is being called.

Transactions ensures the atomicity of the sequence of operations. That precisely means, either everything is successful or in case of exception all the queries are rolled back.
When there is a failure in the transaction, Spring closes the connection and releases the resource. If there is no transaction, then no one guarantees when the connection is closed ( It might also get closed after one call returns successfully from the DB and for the next call another connection might be acquired.

As you state that the problem is solved, I stop writing here, for more on Spring refer my blog:[TechieMe](http://techieme.in/techieme/annotation-based-spring-mvc/)